# Redirect Not Processed When Trying to Force Close a Window in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, redirect

I need to be able to hit another URL before force-closing a window, but the following JavaScript just closes the window and does not hit the URL as reported by Fiddler. When I remove the window-closing code, the URL is hit. No matter where I place the line containing the code to hit the URL, it never occurs. What should I do?

```
<1>: $.ajax("Some_URL"); or window.location.replace("Some_URL");

//Close the window without user-prompt
window.open('', '_self', '');
<1>
window.opener='x';
<1>
window.close();
<1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a redirect and immediately close the window, the browser doesn't bother opening the URL because it has no place to display it.

If you start an AJAX request and close the window, the request is cancelled because there's no code to handle the response.

What you can do is start an AJAX request and close the window in the callback:

```
$.get("Some_URL", function() { window.close() });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call a method in the parent/opener window to preform the ajax call before calling window.close();